# Inverse of half a polynomial

Tags: limits, polynomials

I am given the assignment of finding the inverse of the following function:

$$f(x) = x^2 + 4x + 5$$
where $x > -2$.

I can get rid of the $5$ obviously, but then I get stuck. Hints are appreciated.

Comment: Don't get rid of the entire $5$. Complete the square.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:** Complete the square. Then you'll get $$y=(x+2)^2+1$$

If you don't know how to complete the square, feel free to leave a comment and I'll explain.

Comment: Thank you!  Really clear :)

Answer (score 5):

You want to solve $y = x^2 + 4x + 5$ when $x > -2$, or $x^2 + 4x + (5 - y) = 0$. Solving for $x$ using the quadratic formula, we have

$$ x = \frac{-4 \pm \sqrt{16 - 4(5 - y)}}{2} = \frac{-4 \pm \sqrt{4(y - 1)}}{2} = -2 \pm \sqrt{y - 1}.$$

Since $x > -2$, we need to take the solution with the $+$ and so $x = -2 + \sqrt{y - 1}$.

Answer (score 3):

$$x^2+4x+5=y\Longleftrightarrow$$

$$x^2+4x=y-5\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$x^2+4x+4=y-1\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$(x+2)^2=y-1\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$x+2=\pm\sqrt{y-1}\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$x=\pm\sqrt{y-1}-2$$

Comment: You can save typing with \iff for "if and only if".

Comment: Only the plus variant since $x>-2$.